# How to create a notification at a specific time in the future? (Android)

Tags: android, notifications

Right now I want to choose a specific time and send a notification to the user, but the app only sends a notification when running in the background. How can I send a notification when the application is completely closed?

This is my MainActivity.java class

```
package com.vortex.notification;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createNotificationChannel();

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,4);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,48);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,3);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notification_reciver.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
            }
        });


    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "LemubitReminderChanel";
            String description = "Chanel for Lemubit Reminder";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notifyLemubit", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my Notification_reciver.java class

```
package com.vortex.notification;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Notification_reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repating_intent = new Intent(context,Repating_activity.class);
        repating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"notifyLemubit")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                .setContentTitle("Bildirim Başlığı")
                .setContentText("Bildirim Yazısı")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    }
}
```

And this my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vortex.notification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Notification_reciver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I solved it by changing this line

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,0);
```

And in manifest change your receiver from this

```
<receiver android:name=".Notification_reciver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To this:

```
<receiver android:name=".Notification_reciver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I think there is still something wrong. The notification comes when the app is in the background, but not when it is completely closed.

Comment: also try setInexactRepeating() instead of setRepeating()

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, the app works as before.